# variable will not update with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am really stuck at this point. I am trying to create a very basic sliding div that cannot slide more than 750px in a certain direction. I have created the script below, however, although the **#teamInner** div slides with each click **var position** always remains at **0px** which means the **if** statement I have written will not work. Can anybody spot what I have done wrong? Here is the code:

```
var position = ($("#teamInner").css("margin-left"));
var maxRight = "-750px"
var maxLeft = "0px"

function left(){
    $("#teamInner").stop(true, true).animate( {"margin-left":"+=250"},500,'easeOutQuart');
    $("#leftArrow").css("background-position", "50px");
    $("#rightArrow").css("background-position", "100px");
}

function right(){
    $("#teamInner").stop(true, true).animate( {"margin-left":"-=250"},500,'easeOutQuart');
    $("#rightArrow").css("background-position", "100px");
    $("#leftArrow").css("background-position", "50px");

}


$("#leftArrow").click(function(){
if (position <= maxLeft && position >= maxRight) {
    alert(position);
    left();
}
else{
$("#leftArrow").css("background-position", "150px");
}
});

$("#rightArrow").click(function(){
if (position <= maxLeft && position >= maxRight) {
    alert(position);
    right();
}
else{
$("#rightArrow").css("background-position", "0px");
}

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually change the value of `position` every time you animate your `div`.
Put simply, you can just add

```
position = ($("#teamInner").css("margin-left"));
```

in the `left` and `right` functions.

Comment: thanks for this. It certainly solved one problem, but unfortunately created another which I really don't understand. There seems to be a problem with **var maxRight**. If I set it to -750px the **#teamInner** will only move -500px but if I set it to -1000px then **#teamInner** moves forever? I can't get my round that at all.

Comment: You should definitely remove the `px` from the variables if you want to check values against them. Use the `px` only to set the CSS.

Comment: That did it. I changed:
    var position = ($("#teamInner").css("margin-left"));
to:
    var margin = ($("#teamInner").css("margin-left"));
    var position = parseInt(margin);
and then added:
    position = position+250;
to each function.

Thanks for your help.